# How to Import objective-c library into keyBoard extension?

Tags: objective-c, swift, calendar, ios8, custom-keyboard

I am developing a custom keyBoard which have calendar inside it.

So I use [THIS](https://github.com/tjeerdintveen/Vurig-Calendar) obj-c library for calendar and I have done all the necessary steps for importing this library and for testing I display that calendar into the UIView into StoryBoard and I got this:

[image]

Working good with storyBoard but when I try to import its delegate in the same project into `KeyboardViewController.swift` it is complaining like this:

[image]

How can I add this library into `KeyboardViewController.swift`?

Am I missing something?

I want to achieve something like this:

[image]

Comment: have you got any solution? I am facing same probelm!

Comment: Nop I didn't found any solution yet.

Comment: I get solution. Mention Bridging file name in Extension instead of Targets.

Comment: How to import third party library in custom keyboard extension ?